# How can I achieve area fill in the video?

Tags: unity

I am trying to clone a game while learning Unity but I am stuck. How can I achieve area fill like shown in this [Area Fill Example Video](https://youtu.be/5xMLU6T_llU)?

When I searched for it I found the "Flood Fill" algorithm but I am also not sure is it the right solution for this or not. Because in flood fill we have to select a point and check neighbors with same value and convert them, however here how can I decide which point to select and fill?

For example at 00:03 in video I close an area and game fills the area with cubes. With flood fill, if I select a starting point above that line, algorithm can travel through all outer tiles and very well can fill them with cubes also but game fills lesser area there. Why does the game pick a smaller area here? How do they decide which portion of the game field they should fill?

And in 00.11 when cube hit white wall they completely fill the remaining area because I guess they assume it is fully closed. But again my question is how can you decide that? Which methods provide area fills like this?

If someone has an idea or experience about this can points me to the right direction I'd really appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you have some work to do in deciding how you want the game mechanics of *your game* to work, rather than guessing at how an existing game's mechanics work. Once you decide on the rules for your game, transforming those rules to an algorithm is usually reasonably straightforward.

Comment: Actually I want the same thing but as I said I don't know how can you decide an area is closed (frame of the map can also be edges in closed structure) and which portion of the map should be filled.